# creating pdo class in php

Tags: php, oop, class, pdo

I'm trying to create a simple php object to manage a mysql database through pdo. So far it connects to the database just fine and now when I try to insert a new row i get the follow error:

PHP Fatal error:  Using $this when not in object context on line 37

line 37 is $STH = $this->DBH->prepare($sql);

i'm probably just using $this wrong. any help will be appreciated.

```
<?
class Database {
    private $DBH;


    //connects to the database
    function __construct($host,$dbname,$user,$pass) {    
        try {  
            $this->DBH = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $user, $pass);  
        }  
            catch(PDOException $e) {  
            echo $e->getMessage();  
        }
    }

    //inserts into the database
    //$tableName name of the table to insert the info into
    //$items is a multidimensional array of array(column name, value)
    public function insert($tableName,$items){
        $values = array();
        $sql = "INSERT INTO $tableName(";
        $valuePlaceHolder = ''; // holds the question marks at the end of the PDO sql string

        foreach($items as $item){
            $sql .= $item[0] . ',';
            array_push($values, $item[1]);
            $valuePlaceHolder .= '?,';
        }

        // remove the last comma from the sql statement
        $sql = substr($sql,0,-1);
        $valuePlaceHolder  = substr($valuePlaceHolder, 0, -1);

        $sql .= ") values ($valuePlaceHolder)";
        echo $sql;
        $STH = $this->DBH->prepare($sql);
        $STH->execute($values); 
    }

}

?>
```

Comment: We'd need to see how you actually use this class. Seems like you're calling `insert()` as a static method (`Database::insert()`)

Answer (score 0):

read this:

http://www.php.net/manual/es/language.oop5.basic.php#88665

So that you can solve your problem:

```
....
  // remove the last comma from the sql statement
        $sql = substr($sql,0,-1);
        $valuePlaceHolder  = substr($valuePlaceHolder, 0, -1);

        $sql .= ") values ($valuePlaceHolder)";
        echo $sql;
        $STH = Database::DBH;
        $SHT = $SHT->prepare($sql);
        $STH->execute($values); 
.......
```

Comment: From the code above it does not seem like he is defining a function in a class method.

Comment: Not relevant. There's no function declared within this method.

Comment: After edit: it won't solve the problem, since $DBH is not declared as class property. Accessed this way, it's just `null`, so you will get another error.

Comment: can be this:                                                       $STH = Database::DBH;
 $STH = $STH ->prepare($sql);
 $STH ->execute($values);